# mdbootstrap/react disables page scrolling with full page background image

Tags: bootstrap-5, mdbreact

I've been experimenting with front-end development using mdbootstrap/react and I'm really stuck trying to figure out how adding a background image disabled page scrolling:

I have a css block in my stylesheet like this:

```
.background-people {
      background-image: url('../public/img/background-people.jpeg');
      background-attachment: fixed;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

And then my React Layout looks like this:

```
    <div className="bg-image background-people">
        <div className='mask' style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' }}>
            <NavMenu />
            <MDBContainer tag="main">
              {this.props.children}
            </MDBContainer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Everything works great except the page scrolling is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that both the mdbootstrap `bg-image` and `mask` classes set `overflow: hidden` so I just changed the css and the inline styles to set it to `overflow: auto`

Stylesheet:

```
.background-people {
  background-image: url('../public/img/background-people.jpeg');
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

React Layout:

```
<div className="bg-image background-people">
    <div className="mask" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)', overflow: 'auto' }}>
        <NavMenu />
        <MDBContainer tag="main">
          {this.props.children}
        </MDBContainer>
    </div>
</div>
```